# Center/disable clock on login screen

Tags: release-loki, greeter

is it possible to align the clock on login screen / DM to centre or disable it altogether?

The suboptimal placement is driving me nuts :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change the position of the clock on the greeter screen